# Can i use getFilesDir outside of the UI thread

Tags: java, android, static, serializable

I am using Android Studio and I want to know the directory of the application anywhere (means every non-static classes).

The thing is, I am creating a class called Constants to summarize the arbitrary constants in my application. All of my constants are currently static and public except for the constants relating the application's directory. I also implement Serializable to store the constants file inside some file. I will export and import the constants by static methods inside of the Constants class. Going all static really :))

I know that getFilesDir() in the Context class is not static, meaning I can't call something like MainActivity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() where MainActivity extends Activity extends Context.

I can't do something like this too:

```
public transient static MainActivity someActivity = new MainActivity();
public transient static String parentAbsolutePath = someActivity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

Because it will create a new UI thread outside of the existing UI thread.

I know that there is a simple way to do this and that is to pass in a MainActivity to the constructor, like this:

```
class Constants implements Serializable {
    public transient static MainActivity mainActivity;
    public transient static String parentAbsolutePath;

    Constants(MainActivity mainActivity){
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.parentAbsolutePath = mainActivity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

However, it's cumbersome to instantiate `Constants constants = new Constants(this)` in MainActivity, also it lacked modularity and other classes can't use the class without instantiating an object.

So my question is, is there a way to access the application's directory inside class Constants without having to pass a Context-extended object in?

Comment: You can use dagger for this. Look around for dependency injection. It will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't. Alternative workaround, use the Application class. Example:

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    public final Constants constants;

    public void onCreate() {
        constants = new Constants(this);
    }
}
```

and your manifest:

```
<application
android:name="MyApp">
<activity></activity>
</application>
```